# why flume failed to run with the startup script?

Tags: apache-spark, flume

Flume run successfully when I run command

```
/opt/module/flume/bin/flume-ng agent --conf /opt/module/flume/conf --conf-file /opt/module/flume/conf/file_flume_kafka.conf --name a1 -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console
```

```
[root@master bin]# jps
12193 Application
10259 QuorumPeerMain
12310 Jps
10751 Kafka
```

But when I run the startup script that I wrote, it didn't work. The script is as follow:

```sh
#! /bin/bash
case $1 in
"start"){
        for i in master slaves01
        do
                echo " --------启动 $i 采集flume-------"
                ssh $i "/opt/module/flume/bin/flume-ng agent --conf /opt/module/flume/conf --conf-file /opt/module/flume/conf/file_flume_kafka.conf --name a1 -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console"
                echo "-------运行完命令-----------"
            done
};;
"stop"){
        for i in master slaves01
        do
                echo " --------停止 $i 采集flume-------"
                ssh $i "ps -ef | grep file_flume_kafka | grep -v grep |awk '{print \$2}' | xargs kill"
        done
};;
esac
```

The console display:

```
[root@master flume]# f1.sh start
    --------启动 master 采集flume-------
Info: Sourcing environment configuration script /opt/module/flume/conf/flume-env.sh
Info: Including Hive libraries found via () for Hive access
+ exec /opt/module/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/java -Xmx20m -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console -cp '/opt/module/flume/conf:/opt/module/flume/lib/*:/lib/*' -Djava.library.path= org.apache.flume.node.Application --conf-file /opt/module/flume/conf/file_flume_kafka.conf --name a1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Lists
        at org.apache.flume.node.Application.main(Application.java:346)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.Lists
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 1 more
-------运行完命令-----------
    --------启动 slaves01 采集flume-------
Info: Sourcing environment configuration script /opt/module/flume/conf/flume-env.sh
Info: Including Hive libraries found via () for Hive access
+ exec /opt/module/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/java -Xmx20m -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console -cp '/opt/module/flume/conf:/opt/module/flume/lib/*:/lib/*' -Djava.library.path= org.apache.flume.node.Application --conf-file /opt/module/flume/conf/file_flume_kafka.conf --name a1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Lists
        at org.apache.flume.node.Application.main(Application.java:346)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.Lists
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 1 more
-------运行完命令-----------
```

Type "jps":

```
[root@master bin]# jps
10259 QuorumPeerMain
12539 Jps
10751 Kafka
[root@master bin]#
```

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

If your situation is similar to mine running on an Ubuntu machine, you can try the method I tried successfully.

You might delete the default `guava11*.jar` in the lib folder of flume, right?
Under normal circumstances, after deleting this jar, flume will look for `$HADOOP_HOME` and use the guava in hadoop. then you go to copy `guava*.jar` in hadoop to flume,

```
cp /opt/module/hadoop-3.1.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/guava-27.0-jre.jar /opt/module/flume-1.9.0/lib/
```

it should be just fine, it may be a problem of environment variables.

---

Linux environment variables, whether to log in and whether to access interactively, determine the loading order of `/etc/profile` and `/etc/profile.d/*.sh` and `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile` or other files.
The steps for Ubuntu to find environment variables seem to be different from CentOS. I am not very proficient in the specifics. I just know that there is such a sequence. Change the environment variable in the same location on CentOS and Ubuntu, ssh to the remote machine to execute a certain command, maybe one can find the command, the other may not find the command.